# bash for loop on directories with symbols

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I'm trying to create a for loop on folders that contain spaces, comma's and parenthesis. For example: 
`Italy - Rimini (Feb 09, 2013)`

First it scans a parent folder /albums for sub-folders that look like in the example above. Then it executes a curl actions on files in thoses sub-folders. It works fine if the sub-folders do not contain spaces, comma's or other symbols.

```sh
for dir in `ls /albums`;
do
    for file in /albums/$dir/*
    do
            curl http://upload.com/up.php -F uploadfile[]=@"$file" > out.txt
            php process.php 
    done
    php match.php
done
```

But if there are such symbols, it seems the the curl bit gets stuck - it can't find the $file (probably because $dir is incorrect).

I could replace all the symbols in the sub-dirs or remove them or rename the folders to 001, 002 and it works flawlessly. But before resorting to that I'd like to know if it can be solved using bash tricks while keeping the sub-folder name intact?

Comment: read about `find -print0 | xargs ... ` here on StackOverflow. 100's of exmamples. Good luck.

Comment: It's not good to iterate over output of `ls`, as the filename may contain funky characters like `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Familiarize yourself with the concept of *word splitting* of your shell. Then realize that using `ls` to get a list of files with spaces is asking for trouble. Instead, use shell globbing and then quote expansions:

```sh
cd /albums
for dir in *; do
   for file in /albums/"$dir"/*; do
     echo  x"$dir"x"$file"x
   done
   php match.php
done
```

Comment: That looks better. I got a bit further now. Thanks! I found out that cURL doesn't support uploading files containing a comma. https://code.google.com/p/plowshare/issues/detail?id=550

Answer (score 0):

For problems with spaces in filenames, you have to change the IFS to

```
IFS='
'
```

which tells the shell, that only linebreaks are file separators. By default IFS is set to tabs, spaces and linebreaks.

So just put this before the loop begins, and it will work with filenames that contains spaces.

And of course put quotes around your variablenames.